# Is there a global variable in Java for the length of day?

Tags: java, time

I don't want to write `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` in my code but instead use a more readable static `DAY` variable.

I know that I can myself define the variable by writing

```
private static final long DAY =  24*60*60*1000;
```

However this seems to me like a basic function. Is it covered in the standard library somewhere?

Comment: You do know the length of a day isn't strictly fixed?

Comment: @Tunaki : Yes, but for my usecase the deviation doesn't matter. If Java has a builtin function that actually can provide the length of a specific day, I would also be happy about knowing it.

Comment: The JDK has date and time functionality (especially with Java 8) that can handle things a lot better. What you have isn't basic, it's bad.

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ explore this library its a rich one for Date Time

Comment: The best way to manipulate dates is to keep them as dates. That saves you an awful lot of trouble that you'd run into if you convert everything to milliseconds. I know it is very tempting but don't reinvent the wheel, particularly such a complicated wheel as date/time handling. Slightly different scenario, but [it's a really funny story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofDays-long-) API of the `java.time` package in Java 8 `java.time.Duration.ofDays(1).getSeconds()`.

Just store that in a public static field:
`public static final long SECONDS_IN_DAY = Duration.ofDays(1).getSeconds()`

Your method of interest would the [`ofDays(long)` method:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofDays-long-)

> Obtains a Duration
>   representing a number of standard 24 hour days. The seconds are
>   calculated based on the standard definition of a day, where each day
>   is 86400 seconds which implies a 24 hour day. The nanosecond in second
>   field is set to zero.
>
> Parameters: days - the number of days, positive or negative
>   Returns: a
>   Duration, not null
>   Throws: ArithmeticException - if the input days
>   exceeds the capacity of Duration

Follow that up with a call to the [`getSeconds()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#getSeconds--) on the same Duration API:

> Gets the number of seconds in this duration. The length of the
>   duration is stored using two fields - seconds and nanoseconds. The
>   nanoseconds part is a value from 0 to 999,999,999 that is an
>   adjustment to the length in seconds. The total duration is defined by
>   calling this method and getNano().
>
> A Duration represents a directed distance between two points on the
>   time-line. A negative duration is expressed by the negative sign of
>   the seconds part. A duration of -1 nanosecond is stored as -1 seconds
>   plus 999,999,999 nanoseconds.
>
> Returns: the whole seconds part of the length of the duration,
>   positive or negative

Answer (score 0):

A possibility in Java 8 would be `java.time.Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis()`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create the variable as shown in your code example on your question. There is no need to import anything.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you don't need such constants at all. [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) available since JDK 1.5 is extremely useful to convert durations between time units, like:

```
long millis  = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
long seconds = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours);

// or, if you still need a constant
static final long DAY = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
```

The only disadvantage is that a `long` is always returned, so if actual result is not a whole number, it is truncated.